# Moment.js while loop in javascript, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, momentjs

The code supposes to fill the array with dates between given start and end dates. I am using Node.js.

```
var startDate = moment(startDay);
var endDate = moment(endDay);
var datesBetween = [];

var startingMoment = startDate;


while(startingMoment <= endDate) {
    datesBetween.push(startingMoment);
    startingMoment.add(1, 'days');
}

console.log(datesBetween);
```

Comment: must it be sync?

Comment: You are pushing same object to each index in array. Will all have same date based on last iteration of the loop since they are the same object

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `<>` in the editor. There is no particular reason your code should not work as expected

Comment: Why is this tagged [asynchronous]? The code you posted has nothing to do with asynchrony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new object each iteration otherwise you are pushing the same object reference into array each time. They will all end up with last date since it is all the same object

You can use [`moment.clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) to clone the object each time

```js
var startDay = new Date(2018,1,1);
var endDay = new Date(2018,1,4);

var startDate = moment(startDay);
var endDate = moment(endDay);
var datesBetween = [];

var startingMoment = startDate;


while(startingMoment <= endDate) {
    datesBetween.push(startingMoment.clone());// clone to add new object
    startingMoment.add(1, 'days');
}

console.log(datesBetween);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```